# Динамическое обновление Fragment в ViewPager2 в Android

Tags: java, android, fragmentpageradapter

Всем привет!

Нашёл реализацию динамического обновления фрагмента для FragmentPagerAdapter и первой версии ViewPager (https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/update-fragment-viewpager/), но он не подходит для FragmentStateAdapter и ViewPager2 (Android X).

В MainActivity инициализирую фрагменты и ViewPager2:

```
int number = 777;
ViewPager2 viewPager2;
viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);

MainPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(this);
pagerAdapter.setData(number);
viewPager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

В MainPagerAdapter я создаю фрагменты так:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
{
    private int number;

    public MainPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity)
    {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    public void setData(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                bundle.putInt("number", number);
                fragment1.setArguments(bundle);

                return fragment1;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                bundle.putInt("number", number);
                fragment2.setArguments(bundle);

                return fragment2;
            }
        }

        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Код Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
    
    public void check()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

В примере по ссылке, фрагмент можно получить из MainActivity через метод getFragment() в MyPagerAdapter, в конструктор которого передаётся FragmentManager, но FragmentStateAdapter позволяет такую перегрузку методов.

Подскажите, как правильно обновить данные во фрагменте из его активити? В моё случае: как вызвать метод check() в Fragment1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что ViewPager 2 основан на RecyclerView, а значит там применимы те же способы обновления элементов, что и в RecyclerView.

Собственно, что вы можете сделать? Вы можете хранить в вашем FragmentAdapter список ваших фрагментов так же как и в RecyclerView. Вы можете подготавливать их как в Activity и оттуда с помощью метода передавать:

```
public void update(List<Fragment> fragments){
    this.fragments = fragmtnts;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Так и просто внутри самого адаптера при создании добавлять в список.

```
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(position: Int) {
    Fragment fragment = // ваша логика создания фрагмента
    fragments.add(fragment);
    return fragment
}
```

И вы можете создать для себя метод вроде такого:

```
public Fragment getFragmentById(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}
```

Собственно дальше вы спокойно передаете в него нужные вам методы.

**НО.** Здесь есть большое НО, подобная работа с фрагментами не очень рекомендуема, потому что здесь кроется много подводных камней:

- вы должны убедится что ваш фрагмент сейчас видим для пользователя
- вы должны убедится что в нем есть нужный вам метод (особенно если эти фрагменты разные)
- и вообще работа с фрагментами через методы фрагментов из активити является плохой практикой.

Для таких штук хорошо подходит [SharedViewModel](https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments). Можно конечно еще реализовать интерфейс во фрагментах и общаться с фрагментов через интерфейс, это лучше чем, но не намного. А вообще хорошо бы если ваш фрагмент сам обрабатывал подобные состояния. Но в общем тут решать вам.

Comment: Я еще немного дополнил. Учтите это при написании вашего приложения

Comment: У меня всё ещё завязано на Presenter, из которого я получаю данные, которые пришли с сервера. Сначала я отправляю запрос (например на загрузку фото) из фрагмента в presenter, привязывая view фрагмента (например MainActivity), а после успешного ответа от сервера вызываю метод из MainActivity, который должен обновить фрагмент (например сообщить, что фото загружено и отобразить его).

Comment: Тогда мне кажется вам лучше пошарить этот презентер для ваших фрагментов, чтоб они могли получать от него уведомления. Или еще лучше использовать паттерн Observer в котором при переходе в onResume каждый фрагмент будет подспиываться на изменения, а при уходе в onStop фрагмент будет отписываться. А сам презентер будет просто слать изменения все подписчикам. Так вам не придется за всем этим следить и у вас не будет сильной связанности.

Comment: Посмотрел EventBus Observer. Думаю, что он подойдёт. Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше руками. Сейчас EventBus мало кто использует. Хотя лично сам не могу о нем ничего сказать, т.к. не пользовался от слова совсем. Но слышал о нем не лучшие отзывы. Но если у вас трудности с паттерном Observer то можно и так